# Show hidden div on click fix

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I'm rebuilding a page without the use of any JQuery and I need to hide divs without the use of display none. My hidden divs hold forms from jotform and the display none property is breaking my forms on firefox. My solution is to use pure javascript and switch display with visibility and max height.

Here is my script:

```
 function showDiv(that) {
    var len = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.maxHeight = "0px";
    }
    var val = that.value;
    document.getElementById(val).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById(val).style.maxHeight = "10px";
}
```

My CSS:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height:0px;

}
.button {
    background-color: #cb3778;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

My simplified code:

```
<p><input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv1" value="div1" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
    <input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv2" value="div2" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
    <input type="button" class="button" name="Showdiv3" value="div3" onclick="showDiv(this)" /></p>
<div id="0">Click a button to start</div>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="margin-top:1500px;">div3</div>
```

Heres a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cgrouge/a4wehtcd/2/

As you can see, since the div is only hidden you can still scroll down the page to where the content will be when it is visible. I don't want to page to scroll until the content is visible. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: that's what display: none is for, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @KWeiss the display none is breaking my forms on firefox. I've spoken with jotform support and unfortunately they could not help me with my original landing page. They referred me to this page explaining the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **overflow: hidden**

```
function showDiv(that) {
  var len = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
       document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.height = "0px";
       document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
  var val =  that.value;
  document.getElementById(val).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById(val).style.height = "10px";
  document.getElementById(val).style.overflow = "visible";
}
```

Here is the sample: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2d751x1/1/)

Comment: I've tried that as well and found that it wasn't the fix. I've edited your fiddle to show you an example. My forms are long so on div 3 I put a margin-top style to push the content down the page (simulating a long form). Even when div 3 is hidden you can still scroll down the page to where div 3 content will be when visible.

Comment: If you'll add a margin to visibility:hidden div, the space will be still taken. I don't understand the reason why you can't place a big form under div3 in the sample I've provided? Can you please post the updated fiddle?

Comment: Ok that actually worked! I should have been testing with a form rather than making the div taller. I'll implement this into my page. Thank you!

Comment: any chance you know how to add a scrolling function so that when the form is revealed the top of the form scrolls to the top of the page?

Comment: You can add anchor just before the form and bind the jquery event to scroll to that point: `$(document).scrollTop( $("#header").offset().top );`

Comment: Something I didn't think about, now that I'm implementing into my form the code is hiding all of my divs. I'm trying to change the naming convention here so that I'm not naming id's as div1 or div2. I tried renaming things in your fiddle and kept breaking it. Why can't I just rename the id's and function?